Upwork API get a token
I have already received the authorization code. But the token cannot be obtained.
Documentation:
https://www.upwork.com/developer/documentation/graphql/api/docs/index.html#auth-authorizationCodeGrant
Endpoint
POST https://api.upwork.com/graphql/api/v3/oauth2/token‍
I do OAuth2 authorization using the league/oauth2-client library
My code:
include "lib/League/autoload.php";

use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider;

// OAuth2
$provider = new GenericProvider([
    'clientId'                => '*****',
    'clientSecret'            => '*****',
    'redirectUri'             => '********',
    'urlAccessToken'          => 'https://api.upwork.com/graphql/api/v3/oauth2/token',
    'urlAuthorize'            => '', 
    'urlResourceOwnerDetails' => '',
]);


try {
    $accessToken = $provider->getAccessToken('authorization_code', [
        'code' => '*******' 
    ]);

    echo 'Access Token: ' . $accessToken->getToken() . "<br>";
    echo 'Expires: ' . $accessToken->getExpires() . "<br>";
} catch (\League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Exception\IdentityProviderException $e) {
    exit($e->getMessage());
}

After execution, I get an error:
Fatal error: Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: Invalid response received from Authorization Server. Expected JSON. in /lib/League/league/oauth2-client/src/Provider/AbstractProvider.php:637
If you do a normal POST CURL request, Upwork returns an HTML page with the title "Just moment..." and other content and nothing else happens..
Please tell me how to get this token.

'If you do a normal POST CURL request, Upwork returns an HTML page with the title "Just moment..."' - likely, your request via the library got the same response, and therefor it complains about it not being JSON. Such "just a moment" pages are often part of some sort of "bot protection" - but applying that to an API, would really not make much sense IMHO. I think you should contact the API provider and ask them, if they might have anything like that in place - perhaps even accidentally.
